# Logo detection with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect a brands logo in some samples, but I couldn't get any useable results. With `cvBlobs` I found all related red image regions without any problem, but now I must understand which have ULKER logo. I thought a simple **SURF** alg. will do the job (by looking successes of other similar programs)
but the results a far from being good. Also I tried to apply `cvCanny` before any processing to get an edge-representation of logos and eleminate background but there is no difference. Can you please help and tell me what I am doing wrong?
[logo](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/ulkerv.jpg/) , [sample](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/redobjectblob2.jpg/) and the code

```
int find(IplImage* image, IplImage* object)
{
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    cvNamedWindow("Object", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("Object Correspond", 1);

    static CvScalar colors[] =
    {
            {{0,0,255}},
            {{0,128,255}},
            {{0,255,255}},
            {{0,255,0}},
            {{255,128,0}},
            {{255,255,0}},
            {{255,0,0}},
            {{255,0,255}},
            {{255,255,255}}
    };

    CvSeq* objectKeypoints = 0, *objectDescriptors = 0;
    CvSeq* imageKeypoints = 0, *imageDescriptors = 0;
    int i;
    CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(100, 0);

    IplImage *objectGray = cvCreateImage(cvSize(object->width, object->height), object->depth,1);
    IplImage *objectSobel = cvCreateImage(cvSize(object->width, object->height), IPL_DEPTH_16S,1);
    cvCvtColor( object, objectGray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    cvCanny(objectGray,objectGray,50,20,3);
    //cvConvertScale(objectSobel,objectGray);

    IplImage *imageGray = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), image->depth,1);
    IplImage *imageSobel = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_16S,1);
    cvCvtColor( image, imageGray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    cvCanny(imageGray,imageGray,50,10,3);
    //cvSobel(imageGray,imageSobel,dx,dy,ks);
    //cvConvertScale(imageSobel,imageGray);

    double tt = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cvExtractSURF( objectGray, 0, &objectKeypoints, &objectDescriptors, storage, params ,0);

    printf("Object Descriptors: %d\n", objectDescriptors->total);
    printf("Object Keypoints: %d\n", objectKeypoints->total);

    cvExtractSURF( imageGray, 0, &imageKeypoints, &imageDescriptors, storage, params ,0);
    printf("Image Descriptors: %d\n", imageDescriptors->total);
    printf("Image Keypoints: %d\n", imageKeypoints->total);
    tt = (double)cvGetTickCount() - tt;

    printf( "Extraction time = %gms\n", tt/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.));

    CvPoint src_corners[4] = {{0,0}, {objectGray->width,0}, {objectGray->width, objectGray->height}, {0, objectGray->height}};
    CvPoint dst_corners[4];     

    if( locatePlanarObject( objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors, imageKeypoints,
            imageDescriptors, src_corners, dst_corners ))
    {
        for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            CvPoint r1 = dst_corners[i%4];
            CvPoint r2 = dst_corners[(i+1)%4];
            cvLine( image, cvPoint(r1.x, r1.y ),
                    cvPoint(r2.x, r2.y ), colors[6] );
        }
    }
    vector<int> ptpairs;

    flannFindPairs( objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors, imageKeypoints, imageDescriptors, ptpairs );
    for( i = 0; i < (int)ptpairs.size(); i += 2 )
    {
        CvSURFPoint* r1 = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( objectKeypoints, ptpairs[i] );
        CvSURFPoint* r2 = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( imageKeypoints, ptpairs[i+1] );
        CvPoint center;
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound(r2->pt.x);
        center.y = cvRound(r2->pt.y);
        radius = cvRound(r2->size*1.2/9.*2);
        cvCircle( image, center, radius, colors[0], 1, 8, 6 );
    }


    cvShowImage( "Object Correspond", image );
    cvMoveWindow( "Object Correspond",400,400);
    for( i = 0; i < objectKeypoints->total; i++ )
    {
        CvSURFPoint* r = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( objectKeypoints, i );
        CvPoint center;
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound(r->pt.x);
        center.y = cvRound(r->pt.y);
        radius = cvRound(r->size*1.2/9.*2);
        cvCircle( object, center, radius, colors[0], 1, 8, 6 );
    }
    cvShowImage( "Object", object );   
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvDestroyWindow("Object");
    cvDestroyWindow("Object Correspond");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I may overuse it, but I will have to recommend template matching in that scenario.

Comment: The problem is my template (logo) size mostly bigger than the sample

Comment: Also i know that rotation and scale will be a problem for me. As you see products at shelves are not always well placed.

Comment: If logo is bigger, reduce its size. Have you tried find_obj.c sample that come with OpenCV samples?

Comment: Did you looked at the sample images. Its not a single issue. The way i have to go is some kind of pyramids and surf does it. And yes i copied mostly from find_obj.c :)

Comment: Check out [The Unlogo Project](http://unlogo.org/).

Comment: i will look at codes and inform you thanks.